# How can use two variables in one loop

Tags: bash

I have two loops but I don't know if its possible put all together:

First, I merge two diferents ids from the same sample:

```
samples="sample01 sample02 sample03"
for s in ${samples}
do
    cat ${s}_id1.txt ${s}_id2.txt > ${s}_id12.txt
done
```

With this I count how many data are unique in my sample.txt with a range from 19 - 41 and put the result in count.txt

```
for ((t=17, i=1; t<43; t=t+2, i++))
do 
    echo "[$i] Iteration - t = $t"`
    unique.py -o count.txt -t $t sample.txt
done
```

What I want is put the diferents values for `$t` for each  `${s}` sample_id12.txt element. Something like this:

```
samples="sample01 sample02 sample03"
for s in ${samples} ¿counter?
do
    cat ${s}_id1.txt ${s}_id2.txt > ${s}_id12.txt
    unique.py -o count.txt -t $t ${s}_id12.txt
    rm ${s}_id12.txt
done
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a nested loop? Aside from that, I don't understand what the $i is for - it doesn't seem referenced at all.

Comment: Sorry, is for my log `echo "[$i] Iteration - t = $t"`

Comment: Not really knowing the nested loops. I've learned something new. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested loop example

```
samples="sample01 sample02 sample03"
for s in ${samples}
do
    cat ${s}_id1.txt ${s}_id2.txt > ${s}_id12.txt
    for ((t=17, i=1; t<43; t=t+2, i++))
    do 
        echo "[$i] Iteration - t = $t"
        unique.py -o count.txt -t $t ${s}_id12.txt
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ((t=17; t<43; t=t+2))
do 
    samples="sample01 sample02 sample03"
    for s in ${samples}
    do
        cat ${s}_id1.txt ${s}_id2.txt > ${s}_id12.txt
        unique.py -o count.txt -t $t ${s}_id12.txt
    done
done
```

With this I get each file with ,`t` between 17-41 in `count.txt` file (`unique.py` overwrites the results with the `t` corresponding to each value in each samplefile.

```
sample01_id12.txt 
sample02_id12.txt
sample03_id12.txt
```

Comment: I believe that you should up-vote and probably accept @Dani_I solution as he helped you get the solution.